# Flow player not playing video while sharing to facebook account

Tags: javascript, facebook

```html
<meta property="og:url" content="http://103.231.125.106/nesos/fbsharenew.jsp" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Flowplayer" />
<meta property="og:type" content="movie" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Sharing plugin custom configured" />
<meta property="og:description" content="The Sharing plugin in a custom configuration" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="360" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="640" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://d12zt1n3pd4xhr.cloudfront.net/fp/img/flow_eye.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://d12zt1n3pd4xhr.cloudfront.net/fp/img/flow_eye.jpg" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video"
   content="http://103.231.125.106/nesos/videoappsuser/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf?config={'clip':{'url':'http://103.231.125.106/nesos/videoappsuser/SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.flv'}}" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url"
   content="https://103.231.125.106/nesos/videoappsuser/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf?config={'clip':{'url':'https://103.231.125.106/nesos/videoappsuser/SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.flv'}}" />
```

http://103.231.125.106/nesos/fbsharenew.jsp
**Video shared on facebook but not playing when i clicked  in flow player, play button**

Comment: Your `og:video:secure_url` does not seem to be accessible. When I try to load it in my browser, I only get timeouts.

Comment: @CBroe dude  video shared perfectly, but not playing video,so what i do?please help me

Comment: You need to make your video accessible, which it currently does not seems to be. I am not talking about the URL you are sharing, but about the video itself. `https://103.231.125.106/nesos/videoappsuser/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf?config={'clip':{'url':'https://103.231.125.106/nesos/videoappsuser/SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.flv'}}` does not load _at all_ in my browser. And as long as it doesn’t _load_, you can not expect it to _play_ either.